# Double valued drop-down menu in libreoffice-calc

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

Suppose I have a spreadsheet like this in libreoffice-calc:

[image]

Now I want to have a drop down list in `A3` to choose between the strings in `E3` (`Text a`) and `H3` (`Text b`) such that automatically cell `B3` contains the string from `F3` i.e. `Value a` if `Text a` is chosen and `Value b` if `Text b` is selected in my drop-down menu.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use an IF formula in B3 that will look at A3 to determine which cell to pull data from. Here's the formula you'd use in this case:

```
=IF(A3="text a", F3, I3)
```

Of course, replace `text a` with whatever you are actually using.